# How do i update user alias in Salesforce

Tags: user-management, user

I know that the alias in User record is auto-populated. However, I would like to update this as the last name was entered incorrectly. It seems like Salesforce do not allow me to do so. How do I edit/update the alias in existing User Record?

Comment: Cheryl, you may want to specify whether this is by using the user interface or anything else.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to update the alias field from the page layout itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it in a dev. org. and I was able to update the Alias field using the standard UI.

Go to Setup -> Users -> Select User -> Edit -> Enter Alias -> Save.

Comment: Thanks Davin! I finally found that there's an existing validation rule in my org that restrict me to update the field in the first place.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
User u = [SELECT Id, Alias FROM User WHERE ...]; // Get the user you want to update
u.Alias = 'MyNewAlias';
update u;

system.debug(u.Alias);
```